# How does TAB auto-complete find options to complete?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

And how does it also autocomplete aliases?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Depending on the command:

- Someone may have written a function to generate possible completions of arguments, including options. You'll find functions for some commands in `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` (or a different location on some systems). These functions are registered with the [`complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-complete-385) [built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) (e.g. `complete -F _find find` tells bash to call the `_find` function when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on a `find` command). They use the [`compgen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-compgen-384) built-in to tell bash “here are the possible completions”.
- For some commands, bash will call the command with the argument `--help` and parse the output. Such commands can be registered with the [`complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-complete-385) built-in, e.g. `complete -F _longopt ls`. `_longopt` is in fact a completion generation function, that happens to parse a command's output rather than use a fixed list. (There are other more specialized completion functions that parse a command's output to generate possible completions; look in `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` for examples.)
- For things like aliases, the completion function looks them up in bash's internal tables. The [`complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-complete-385) built-in has options for that, e.g. `-A` for aliases.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the file

> /etc/bash_completion

and observe the files from the directory:

> /etc/bash_completion.d

You will find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Support for bash completion is provided in Debian and Ubuntu by the [bash completion package](http://packages.qa.debian.org/b/bash-completion.html). You also usually need to uncomment the following in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and/or `.bashrc` to source the bash completion files. The following is from `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

for this to work. I usually uncomment it in both. The handling of interactive/login shells in Debian is a bit of a mess.

Similar comments presumably apply to other distributions, though maybe they enable the sourcing by default.