# How to pipe the list of commands displayed by "tab complete"?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, autocomplete

When using commands in bash I like the **double-<kbd>Tab</kbd>** option to display the available commands. Some commands have more possible matches than others. Example: here is just some of the output after typing `git` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
$ git
git                       git-effort                git-quick-stats
git-alias                 git-extras                git-reauthor
git-archive-file          git-feature               git-rebase-patch
git-authors               git-filechange-search     git-receive-pack
git-back                  git-force-clone           git-refactor
git-blametool             git-fork                  git-release
git-branch_               git-fresh-branch          git-rename-branch
git-branchz               git-graft                 git-rename-tag
git-bug                   git-gs_blametool          git-repl
git-bulk                  git-gs_branch_            git-reset-file
git-changelog             git-gs_changes            git-root
git-changes               git-gs_diffc              git-rscp
git-chore                 git-guilt                 git-scp
git-clang-format          git-ignore                git-sed
git-clang-format-6.0      git-ignore-io             git-setup
git-clear                 git-info                  git-shell
git-clear-soft            gitk                      git-show-merged-branches
git_commit_r              git-lfs                   git-show-tree
git-commits-since         git-line-summary          git-show-unmerged-branches
git-contrib               git-local-commits         git-squash
git-count                 git-lock                  git-stamp
```

Is there a way I can pipe the output of the double-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to somewhere, like to `grep`?  I found a related post ([How does TAB auto-complete find options to complete?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12356/114401)), but I'm still not sure how to implement piping the output to `grep`.

Comment: How exactly do you imagine you would enter the `grep` regex? `(y or n or g[rep])`?  I hate to sound pessimistic, but I doubt this could be done without adding it to the bash code.

Comment: [Related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25935/how-to-output-string-completions-to-stdout)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For commands use `compgen -c`. The word `compgen` apparently stands for "completion generator". From `help compgen` (emphasis added):

> `compgen: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat]  [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix]  [-S suffix] [word]`
>
> Display possible completions depending on the options.
>
> **Intended to be used from within a shell function generating possible**
> **completions.  If the optional WORD argument is supplied, matches against**
> **WORD are generated.**
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.

For extra details, search the `man bash` pages for `compgen`, since it's a built-in bash shell command.

Example usage:

```bash
$ compgen -c bas
basename
base64
bashbug
bash
```

This output you can simply pipe to `grep`. Example:

```bash
$ compgen -c bas | grep bug
bashbug
```

Comment: +1 For the command... Next interesting part could be how to make a keyboard shortcut for this.

Comment: See also: [List all binaries from `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120786/114401)

Answer (score 3):

Based on @salutis's answer I created a script which I called `comp` and stored in `~/bin/comp` that searches `commands`', `aliases`, and `builtins`, (option flag `-cab` see [the bash man entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)), with an optional second parameter which, if present, pipes the output to `grep` and searches for the second parameter.

```
Usage: comp string [keyword-for-grep]
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo usage: comp string [keyword-for-grep]
    echo 
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    compgen -cab -- $1
    exit
fi

compgen -cab -- $1 | grep -i $2
```

Personally I would also be interested in figuring out a way to remove the last command from the shell history in the script (something related to `history -d`) so that when searching `bash` history I won't find `comp` entries. I know I can also do this with `HISTIGNORE` but linux is pretty powerful so there must be a way to do it from the script file, too - right?

Comment: Of course you can adjust this to suit your needs, but it should get you started.

Answer (score -3):

Why not find what you are looking for?

Example:

```
find / -name ec2* -executable -type f -perm -og+rx -print
```

Knowing your use case I can create a more detailed command example.

Comment: In other words you can reimplement whatever bash's completion does. Sure, but that's not practical, and it's not what the question is about.