# How to output string completions to stdout?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

Some of the `git` commands have many options, and it would often be useful to search through them for the one I need - I was just looking for the option which controls the <kbd>TAB</kbd> width in `git-gui`, but there are about 200 completions for `git config`. An obvious workaround is to copy all the completions into an editor and search through them, but I'd rather do

```
[something] | grep tab
```

There are no `man` or `info` pages for `compgen`, `help compgen` doesn't even explain its own options, and there's no auto-complete for `compgen` (how's that for irony?).

PS: [`compgen -A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511683/bash-get-list-of-commands-starting-with-a-given-string) doesn't work.

PPS: This is not a question about `git-gui` - The [solution to the tab width question](https://superuser.com/questions/268208/change-tabsize-in-git-gui) was elsewhere.

PPPS: This is *not* about auto-completing commands, only *command parameters*.

Comment: This is very similar to [How to pipe the output of "tab complete"?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23900/how-pipe-the-output-of-tab-complete), but the accepted answer there was specifically for completing commands, not arguments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following function, which use the same way `sudo` auto-completion generate the completion list:

```
comp() {
    local COMP_LINE="$*"
    local COMP_WORDS=("$@")
    local COMP_CWORD=${#COMP_WORDS[@]}
    ((COMP_CWORD--))
    local COMP_POINT=${#COMP_LINE}
    local COMP_WORDBREAKS='"'"'><=;|&(:"
    # Don't really thing any real autocompletion script will rely on
    # the following 2 vars, but on principle they could ~~~  LOL.
    local COMP_TYPE=9
    local COMP_KEY=9
    _command_offset 0
    echo ${COMPREPLY[@]}
}
comp git config ''
```

where `_command_offset` is defined in bash-completion (package).

**NOTE: the function need to be run in a interactive shell (i.e. if it is in a file, the file need to be sourced instead of just run.) or the necessary completion rules/functions will not be defined.**

PS. `compgen -A` only works for builtin actions, what you should have tried (but doesn't work either) is `compgen -F` (or actually `compgen -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git`). The reason this doesn't work (and doc for bash built-in commands including compgen/complete) can be found in [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: @l0b0 hopefully works in all cases.

Comment: Excellent, it works! I did a couple minor tweaks and now it's in [my .bash_aliases](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/73f670e1a2dc7aa5ee2506d187bb3fab04578a78) for good. You might want to prune so only the solution is left, but there's no doubt you get the bounty. I'll remove my discussion comments since they are not relevant anymore.

Comment: I have found that using this in the interactive shell can destroy the tab-completion already in place. Making each of the variables local to the function solves that problem. (e.g. `local COMP_LINE="$*"`)

Comment: @A.L.Flanagan Good point. Updated.