# How can I loop over possible completions?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'd like to be able to get my hands on an array of possible completions for a given partial command. For example, the partial command `service um` has the following possible completions:

```
$ service um<TAB><TAB>
umountfs      umountnfs.sh  umountroot
```

I'd like to have a function `completions` with the following behavior:

```
$ for x in $(completions 'service um'); do
> echo $x
> done
umountfs
umountnfs.sh
umountroot
```

### Partial progress: what I've learned so far

Here is an approach which I think can be made into a full answer. I'd definitely like to see that full answer, but given that the relatively simple `<TAB><TAB>` gives the same functionality in a non-programmatic way, it feels like there could also be a slicker solution.

I can find out that the completion mechanism for the `service` command is the `_service` function:

```
$ complete -p service
complete -F _service service
```

When this completion function `_service` is called, a bunch of environment variables are set (namely `COMP_{LINE,POINT,KEY,TYPE,WORDS,CWORD}`; see [the bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion)), the function is given as arguments the command being completed, word being completed, and previous word, and it populates `COMPREPLY` with the possible completions. So my desired `completions` function could be defined something like this:

```
function completions() {
    # Produce an array of tokens in the input.
    read -a words <<< $1

    # Use "complete -p ${words[0]}" to determine how the 
    # completions are computed. This could be complicated
    # if complete is given flags other than -F.
    completion_func=???

    # Set all those COMP_* environment variables appropriately.

    # Run the function to populate COMPREPLY. This version
    # assumes words has length at least 2, but that can be
    # fixed.
    $completion_func ${words[0]} ${words[-1]} ${words[-2]}

    echo ${COMPREPLY[@]}
}
```

Aside from the complexity relative over `<TAB><TAB>`, a drawback of this approach is that it changes the environment.

Comment: [Related meta discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3385/52236).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary function that I think can serve as starting point. It can fail in several ways, hopefully others here can improve:

```bsh
completions () (
    if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
    fi

    IFS="$COMP_WORDBREAKS" read -a words <<<"$1"
    complete_setting=($(complete -p "${words[0]}"))
    complete_optstring=":abcdefgjksuvprDEo:A:G:W:F:C:X:P:S:"
    while getopts "$complete_optstring" option "${complete_setting[@]:1}"
    do
        case $option in
            F) complete_functon="$OPTARG"
                ;;
            *) # Run around screaming!                    
                ;;
        esac
    done
    COMP_WORDS=("${words[@]}")
    COMP_LINE="$1"
    COMP_POINT="${#COMP_LINE}"
    COMP_CWORD=$((${#COMP_WORDS[@]} - 1))
    "$complete_functon" 
    printf "%s\n" "${COMPREPLY[@]}"
)
```

Notes:

- If you're using this as a function for your interactive shell, the initial sourcing isn't needed.
- `complete` looks for words split using `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, so we set `IFS` to it for `read`.
- `complete -p` prints out the current completion setting in a reusable way, so we can go about parsing the options the way it would.
- The function uses a subshell (`()` instead of `{}`), so your current environment shouldn't be disturbed.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Looking at the answer to the question this was deduped to (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31023/79064), it looks like you can avoid running around screaming using the meta-completion command _command_offset (which will also take care of parsing the options). I haven't had a chance to try it out yet.