# Is there any command that mimics the double tab list in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to get the same possible autocomplete list as hitting [Tab][Tab] in bash but with a command. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: In theory you could `echo -e "\011\011" | bash` (`011` is tab char), but in practice I don't think that will work, ever.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `compgen`, which is typically the program that's invoked when you hit tab twice.

```
$ compgen -c c
cls
case
coproc
command_not_found_handle
caller
cd
command
compgen
complete
compopt
continue
clamd
cracklib-check
cpgr
cupsreject
cupsdisable
cupsaccept
cron
cppw
<100's more lines...>
```

It includes shell builtins, too! See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23900/how-to-pipe-the-list-of-commands-displayed-by-of-tab-complete?rq=1) and `man compgen`.

Note the output is sorted for columnisation (what bash will do), not a single line. You can quite easily `sort` the output alphabetically, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean matching files, you may mean:

```
foo<TAB><TAB>
```

This should be an alternative:

```
ls | grep -E '^foo'
```

If you mean matching programs, you may do so for all directories in `$PATH`.

Comment: `ls` for every possible executable in `$PATH`, and then `grep`ing seems like a bad idea to me, YMMV

Comment: When I hit `TAB` twice, I get `Display all 6677 possibilities? (y or n)`, and my `$PATH` isn't even that cluttered. Seems slow to me, anyways.